# If $p=a^2+b^2$ prove these consequences about $\big(\!\frac{a}{p}\!\big)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, legendre-symbol

Suppose odd prime $p=a^2+b^2$, and $a$ is odd and $b$ is even. Prove that if $b\equiv2\pmod4$, then $\left(\dfrac bp\right)=-1$ and if $b\equiv0\pmod4$, then $\left(\dfrac bp\right)=1$.

What I have got is that $p\equiv 1 \pmod4$. I have tried factoring $b$ and splitting up the Legendre symbols. However, I am not sure this gets anywhere because you cannot say much about those. I have also observed that $b \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ when $p\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ and $b \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ when $p\equiv 5 \pmod 8$ if that helps.

Comment: @twnly so "for each $q | b, p $ is a square $\bmod q$, then use quadratic reciprocity on $\prod_j (\frac{q_j}{p})^{e_j}$

Comment: @reuns is right, my proposed solution has some errors. I deleted them.

Comment: is there some reason to expect there is no much simpler solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Write $b=2^rc$ with $c$ odd. Then $p=a^2+b^2\equiv a^2\pmod c$ and so
$\left(\frac pc\right)=1$ (this is a **Jacobi** symbol). As $p\equiv1
\pmod 4$ then $\left(\frac cp\right)=1$ (quadratic reciprocity for
Jacobi symbols).

When $p\equiv1\pmod8$ then $\left(\frac 2p\right)=1$ and so $\left(\frac bp\right)=\left(\frac 2p\right)^r\left(\frac cp\right)=1$. When $p\equiv5\pmod8$ then $\left(\frac 2p\right)=-1$ and also
$r=1$. Therefore $\left(\frac bp\right)=\left(\frac 2p\right)\left(\frac cp\right)=-1$.